# Select multiple row in listview and delete selected records from listview and database aslo

Tags: android, listview

In my application I am showing custom list from database. After selecting few rows of list I want to delete those rows from Listview and database as well. how to do?

Comment: Show your code and efforts here for better help

Answer (score 0):

If your `ListView`'s data is saved in a `List`, add a variable to the item model in `List` to mark the item being selected or not. When delete button clicked, loop through `List` and delete the selected item from `List` and also delete it form DB. Call `Adapter.notifyDatasetChange()` after loop.

Comment: i am getting only the position of selected items. and i am able to fetch whole content of ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>> by usng that position. but not able to get hashmap value by using key

Comment: see the answer i post below

Answer (score 0):

So you should wrap your item like below:

```
public class Item {
    private HashMap<String, String> content;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public HashMap<String, String> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(HashMap<String, String> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

Then you can use position to get the Item and set `isSelected` true or false.And change your `List<HashMap<String, String>>` to `List<Item>`